# INSERT has more target columns than expressions with SELECT in CTE

Tags: sql, postgresql

Trying to fix this CTE, specifically the company_job insert

```
WITH newPerson AS (
    INSERT INTO person (name_first, name_last)
    VALUES ('', '')
    RETURNING person_id
),
newJob AS (
    INSERT INTO job (temp)
    VALUES ('')
    RETURNING job_id
),
newCompany_Job AS (
    INSERT INTO company_job (job_id, company_id, person_id)
    SELECT (j.job_id, 1000, p.person_id) FROM newPerson p, newJob j
)
```

**Error**

```
ERROR:  INSERT has more target columns than expressions
LINE 13:  INSERT INTO company_job (job_id, company_id, person_id)
```

I know I'm close but not sure why it isn't liking the syntax I have already.  I've specified 3 fields and gave it 3 fields so not sure why it's complaining

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**30 years!!** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: @marc_s what do you mean list of tables. Where? This is a CTE, so what part of the CTE are you referring to? I'm selecting data from each CTE result, not tables.  Each insert is returning ONE record in this CTE.  So please be specific on what you mean, how would you rewrite this then?

Comment: you have `SELECT ..... FROM newPerson p, newJob j` - you should use a **proper JOIN` between `newPerson p` and `newJob j` - not just list them as comma-separated tables in a `FROM` clause ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WITH newPerson AS (
    INSERT INTO person (name_first, name_last)
    VALUES ('a', 'b')
    RETURNING person_id
),
newJob AS (
    INSERT INTO job (tmp)
    VALUES ('c')
    RETURNING job_id
)
INSERT INTO company_job (job_id, company_id, person_id) 
    select job_id, 1000, person_id from newPerson,newJob;
```

Comment: thank you.  No `;` needed at the end of the insert... otherwise it works